# Optimization MySQL recommendations

Tags: mysql

I ask for help, please recommend how to improve mysql. Here is my analysis of mysqltuner.

In general, the problem is this, the site works well, but what does not suit me is the login to the site is very long. When entering a username and password, you have to wait 20-30 seconds to enter the system. All suspicions about mysql.
I would be glad to any advice.

```
root@server:~# perl ./mysqltuner.pl
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.8.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(0B)
[--] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty. Assuming log-rotation. Use --server-log={file} for explicit file

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 28.1M (Tables: 254)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] User 'defaultuser'@% does not specify hostname restrictions.
[--] There are 620 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] CVE-2021-2146(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Options). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2154(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: DML). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2162(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Audit Plug-in). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows low privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized update
[!!] CVE-2021-2166(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: DML). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2169(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Optimizer). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2171(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Replication). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.4 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2174(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: InnoDB). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.4 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2179(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Group Replication Plugin). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2180(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: InnoDB). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2194(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: InnoDB). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2226(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Information Schema). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized access to critical data or complete access to all MySQL Server accessible data. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Confidentiality impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:N/A:N)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2307(<= 5.7.33) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Packaging). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.33 and prior and 8.0.23 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows unauthenticated attacker with logon to the infrastructure where MySQL Server executes to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks require human interaction from a person other than the attacker. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized access to critical data or complete access to all MySQL Server accessible data as well as unauthorized update
[!!] CVE-2021-2342(<= 5.7.34) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Optimizer). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.34 and prior and 8.0.25 and prior. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2356(<= 5.7.34) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Replication). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.34 and prior and 8.0.25 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows low privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server as well as unauthorized update
[!!] CVE-2021-2372(<= 5.7.34) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: InnoDB). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.34 and prior and 8.0.25 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 4.4 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:H/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2385(<= 5.7.34) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: Server: Replication). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.34 and prior and 8.0.25 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows high privileged attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server as well as unauthorized update
[!!] CVE-2021-2389(<= 5.7.34) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: InnoDB). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.34 and prior and 8.0.25 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows unauthenticated attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 5.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] CVE-2021-2390(<= 5.7.34) : "Vulnerability in the MySQL Server product of Oracle MySQL (component: InnoDB). Supported versions that are affected are 5.7.34 and prior and 8.0.25 and prior. Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows unauthenticated attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise MySQL Server. Successful attacks of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized ability to cause a hang or frequently repeatable crash (complete DOS) of MySQL Server. CVSS 3.1 Base Score 5.9 (Availability impacts). CVSS Vector: (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:H/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H)."
[!!] 18 CVE(s) found for your MySQL release.

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 20h 32m 9s (12K q [0.173 qps], 2K conn, TX: 4M, RX: 2M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 3.9G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 38.1G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 192.0M global + 257.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 449.1M (11.37% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 38.1G (987.24% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/12K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 0% (1/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.04%  (1/2817)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 424 sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 4% (222 on disk / 5K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (1 created / 2K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 55% (10K hits / 19K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache(615) is upper than number of tables(533)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (19/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (2K immediate / 2K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (3M used / 16M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/43.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 91.0% (366 cached / 33 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/28.1M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (400 %): 256.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.89% (580617 hits/ 581240 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 164.81% (178 hits/ 108 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 286 writes)

-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Restrict Host for 'defaultuser'@'%' to 'defaultuser'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost
    RENAME USER 'defaultuser'@'%' TO 'defaultuser'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost;
    18 CVE(s) found for your MySQL release. Consider upgrading your version !
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://??
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

my.cnf

```
  #
    # The MySQL database server configuration file.
    #
    # You can copy this to one of:
    # - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
    # - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
    # 
    # One can use all long options that the program supports.
    # Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
    # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
    #
    # For explanations see
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
    
    #
    # * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
    #   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
    #
    
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysql]
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/slow_queries.log
long_query_time=2
```

Comment: Could you post your my.cnf for analysis?  There are 18 reported CVE Security Recommendations listed in your MySQLTuner report.  Do you have flexibiity to upgrade to MySQL 5.7.35 that became GA on 2021 07 20 to avoid identified vulnerabilities ?

Comment: yes of course the contents of the file are added

Comment: Thanks for the my.cnf.  Observation, MySQLTuner reported you are running MySQL 5.7.33 but your my.cnf refers to MariaDB.  Are you in transition between these 2 flavors of the DB?  View profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning..

Comment: I apologize copied the old file. again updated which is now relevant.

Comment: You can't tune your way out of a performance problem.  Locate all the SQL statements involved in the login; we will check them.  Also see what non-database tasks are being performed.  Populate your program with print statements writing the time to some log.  Look for a big time gap.

Comment: If you continue to suspect MySQL, follow the advice here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis for more tuning analysis and for using the slowlog.  (The 'tuner' output indicates a memory problem, but does not have enough detail to say where it is coming from.)  Is the system "swapping"?  Are other apps running on the same machine?

Comment: @user16812385 - If this gets closed due to lack of focus, start a new Question, addressing the issues raised in the Comments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After root login and you have MySQL Command Prompt available,

```
SET GLOBAL log_output=FILE;  # to ensure you are writing to files
SET GLOBAL general_log=ON;  # to enable recording all activities
```

Connect to your MySQL with another client session, would log all the
processes required to get through login.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log=OFF;  # to stop recording and take your time
```

analyzing the general log you have captured.

If you do not know your general log file name to analyze,

From root login,

```
SELECT @@general_log_file;  # for the instance to reveal your filename.
```

Good luck, view profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.